# mongodb update operation on shards very slow

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, sharding

I have a little cluster which consists of 3 shards, and every shard is a replica set of 2 real nodes and 1 ARBITER. sharding is enabled on a collection, let's say `coll_words`, key is `title`.

other info:

- `rs.slaveOk()` is on and  `balancer` is off.
- the primary shard of this collection contains around 13M documents, the other 2 secondary ones each contains around 5M.
- average ping between shards is below 1 millis. Pings from mongos to shard is about `3 Millis` with `'connPoolStats'` command.

The typical `find()` response through a mongos like this (`update()` is slow too):

```
mongos> db.coll_words.find({title:'りのフランス'}).explain()
{
    "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
    "shards" : {
        "rsName/IP1:27017,IP2:27017" : [
            {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor title_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "n" : 1,
                "nscannedObjects" : 1,
                "nscanned" : 1,
                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
                "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                "indexOnly" : false,
                "nYields" : 0,
                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                "millis" : 0,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "title" : [
                        [
                            "りのフランス",
                            "りのフランス"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "server" : "SERVER:27017"
            }
        ]
    },
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor title_1",
    "n" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "millisShardTotal" : 0,
    "millisShardAvg" : 0,
    "numQueries" : 1,
    "numShards" : 1,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "title" : [
            [
                "りのフランス",
                "りのフランス"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "millis" : 51
}
```

>

It's really confusing to me, why this *finally* costs **`"millis" : 51`**?

Am I missing something? Any pointers would be great.

**Update:**

Pings from mongos to shard is about `3 Millis` with `'connPoolStats'` command.

```
"replicaSets" : {
        "rs0" : {
            "hosts" : [
                {
                    "addr" : "IP1:27017",
                    "ok" : true,
                    "ismaster" : false,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "secondary" : true,
                    "pingTimeMillis" : 3
                },
                {
                    "addr" : "IP2:27017",
                    "ok" : true,
                    "ismaster" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "secondary" : false,
                    "pingTimeMillis" : 2
                }
            ],
            "master" : 1,
            "nextSlave" : 0
        },
```

Comment: Investigate the issue by creating a test, sharded, balanced, small collection and query it with different keys.

Comment: You say how long the pings between shards are - but that's irrelevant - how long is the ping from mongos to shard rsName?  Clearly the query itself is nearly instant, but it's not getting to/from mongos very fast.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Pings from mongos to shards are nearly instant too, what did you mean exactly by `getting to/from mongos is not very fast`?